# Thin controller queries fat model instead of calling a method

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a thin controller I am using that calls methods from a Fat model. When I call a method that resides in my fat model I get the warnings/errors below. It appears that my controller is attempting to query against the method. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'testMe' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

This is the error I see in the query log:

```
testMe  1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'testMe' at line 1
```

I have dumbed down my model in order to diagnose this issue.

This is the current state of my model (user_entity_license.php):

```
class UserEntityLicense extends UserAgentAppModel {
var $name = 'UserEntityLicense';
var $primaryKey = 'license_id';
var $actsAs = array('Containable');

var $belongsTo = array('UserEntity' => array('className' => 'UserEntity','foreignKey' => 'entity_id'));

public function testMe()
{
    return 'This is a test';
}
}
```

This is the current state of my controller (user_entity_licenses_controller.php):

```
<?php
class UserEntityLicensesController extends UserAgentAppController {

var $name = "UserEntityLicenses";
var $uses = array('UserEntityLicense','UserEntity');

function expiringLicenses()
{
    debug($this->UserEntityLicense->testMe());
}
}
```

Comment: What's going on in your UserAgentAppModel code? Your UserEntityLicense is extending that instead of AppModel, so it could be impacting things. I was able to get this to work okay in my application, and the only other difference I had was that my model wasn't using containable behavior.

Comment: This code resides in a plugin, UserAgentAppModel only extends AppModel. Nothing else is being done. Something else that I have noticed is that this issue only occurs when I am using the using property in my controller.

Comment: Hmm, this is tricky. I'm kind of grasping at straws here, but are you sure your controller is able to find the model, that is, you're actually calling the model class you think you're calling? IIRC, with plugin models in Cake, you have to specify in uses with the notation <pluginname.modelname>, e.g $uses=array('SomePlugin.SomeModel');. If you remove uses, it's probably not finding the model at all and creating a default one.

Comment: That was exactly it. I changed it to UserModule.UserEntityLicense and it worked as expected.

Comment: Sweet, I'll put in an answer so you can accept ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our comment thread, you must specify models found in plugin packages using the notation

`<packagename.modelname>` as seen below:

```
$uses = array('SomePackage.SomeModel');
```

Failure to do this, will cause your controller to be unable to find the model.